# Why getting multiple definition error in C code?

Tags: c

i'm currently doing a simulation of adt in c, and i'm supposed to make a binary search tree invloving strings, i'm currently starting coding but i get this error and it doesnt say where the error comes from, here's the code, can somebody help me.

tree.h

```
#ifndef tree_h
#define tree_h
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct tree_node* node_ptr;

struct tree_node {
    char* word;
    node_ptr leftNode, rightNode;
};

node_ptr start = NULL;

void addItem(char*, int);
void display();

#endif
```

tree.c

```
#include "tree.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


void addItem(char arr[], int mode) {
    node_ptr temp, temp2;
     
    temp = (node_ptr)malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node));
    temp->leftNode=NULL;
    temp->rightNode=NULL;
    
    if(mode == 1){
        temp->word = arr;
        start = temp;
        }
    }  



void display() {
    node_ptr temp;
    temp = start;
    printf("%s", start->word);       
}
```

main.c

```
#include "tree.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main() {
    char word[31];
    
    printf("Enter Root Word: ");
    gets(word);
    addItem(word, 1);
}
```

Comment: On [this page](http://piratepad.net/ep/pad/view/RfsGdRTJcN/rev.501) we confirmed that this is indeed homework and found the problem.

Comment: thanks for helping, combining stackoverflow and piratepad is very helpful for newbies like me. i'll keep in mind to add the needed tags next time. thanks. :)

Comment: @cjBucketHead As you can see, you can post the code here itself rather than on some other site.

Comment: You will probably want to go ahead and "accept" one of the answers below by clicking on the check mark to award some reputation points to the person you feel answered your question best. For doing so, you will get some reputation points as well.

Comment: @Mahesh i'm a bit confused as to how to put codes here. :\

Comment: @cjBucketHead See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is with the statement in `tree.h`.

```
node_ptr start = NULL;
```

And you are including `tree.h` in both `main.c` and `tree.c`. This gives the multiple definition error for the variable `start` which is at global scope. What you actually need is,

```
// tree.h

extern node_ptr start;
```

And have the definition in a single source file like -

```
// tree.c

#include "tree.h"
........
node_ptr start = null;
```

Comment: To more easily see these types of problems, it can be helpful to run only the pre-processor and examine the output manually.

Comment: @bta: I have almost never found that to help me, but I code in C++, so maybe that's related.

Comment: Simplest explanation and solution I've found.  There are a lot of more technical explanations (it feels like I've read them all), but this is the one that brought it all to a very practical point.

Answer (score 7):

The error that you're talking about is:

```
... multiple definition of `start'
```

Since you have `node_ptr start = NULL;` in `tree.h`, each compilation unit that includes `tree.h` will have their own definition of the variable `start`. When it comes time to linking, the linker will see *multiple definitions* of the variable `start` and throw an error.

To avoid this, *define* `start` in `tree.c`:

```
node_ptr start;
```

And then declare `start` as `extern`, so that other compilation units know about it but won't try and define it themselves, in your header file `tree.h`:

```
extern node_ptr start;
```

Answer (score 3):

Your error is that you define:

```
node_ptr start = NULL;
```

In your header file, thus when you import it (regardless of the macro guard) you're going to get two redefinitions of start.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(mode == 1)
{
temp->word = arr;/*here is another error*/
    start = temp;
    }
```

arr is local to main and i think for more nodes you must reuse the arr array for getting input.at that time it reflect in all the nodes as your word of each node point to same memory location.So it is not a option to directly assign.

You have to allocate memory dinamically for the string also.and then use strcpy() function for copying data to dynamic memory location.

ok use this code at that place:-

```
if(mode==1)
 {
  w_len=sizeof(char)*(strlen(arr)+1);//one extra character for null character
  temp->word=malloc(w_len);
  strcpy(temp->word,arr);
  start=temp;
 }
```